# Python unittest setUp function

Tags: python

I am relatively new to Python. According to [unittest.setUp](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp) documentation:

> setUp()
>   Method called to prepare the test fixture. **This is called immediately before calling the test method**; any exception raised by this method will be considered an error rather than a test failure. The default implementation does nothing.

My question about `setUp` is as follows:

In our testing code base, I have seen that we customized the Python testing framework by inheriting from `unittest.TestCase`. Originally, `unittest.TestCase` has names `setUp` and `tearDown`.In the customized class, we have `setUpTestCase` and `tearDownTestCase`. So each time those two functions will be called instead of those original counterparts.

My questions are:

1. How are those `setUp` and `tearDown` functions being called by the underlying test runner?
2. Is it required that those functions used to set up test cases should start with `setUp` and functions used to tear down test cases should start  with `tearDown`? Or it can be named as any valid identifier?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. setUp() and tearDown() methods are automatically used when they are available in your classes inheriting from unittest.TestCase.
2. They should be named setUp() and tearDown(), only those are used when test methods are executed.

Example:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
     self.setUpMyStuff()

  def tearDown(self):
     self.tearDownMyStuff()

class TestSpam(MyTestCase):
  def setUpMyStuff(self):
    # called before execution of every method named test_...
    self.cnx = # ... connect to database

  def tearDownMyStuff(self):
    # called after execution of every method named test_...
    self.cnx.close()

  def test_get_data(self):
    cur = self.cnx.cursor()
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean that they are automatically used when I have function names starts with setUp and tearDown? Their names don't need to be exactly only contain `setUp` and `tearDown`, they could be `setUpThisCase`, is this right?

Comment: setUp() and tearDown() are automatically called before and after the methods named 'test_*', for example 'test_ham' or 'test_spam', are being executed. I don't understand the other question.

Comment: Thanks. That part I understand. My question is: could I change the name of `setUp` to something else like `setUpTest`, if possible, in this case, would `setUpTest` be automatically used?

Comment: I have updated the example to show how to 'rename' the setUp/tearDown. But not sure if that's really useful?

Comment: Thanks. I think it answers my question.